# VS Web Setup Project + VSDB Database project

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, web-deployment-project

I'm using Visual Studio Web Setup Project to instrument web application install kit. Unfortunately, the database is done by a Database Project created by VSTS Database Edition by my colleague(I'm using VSTS Developer Edition). It seems that VS Web Setup Project does not recognize the output of the DB project, so it can't include the out put of the DB project with my web application.

Does someone have done this job before? Or you have some more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current solution I use is just add every file individually, not as project output...